# Posterior probability with limited evidence and unknown number of experiments

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have two coins A,B with different probability of heads $P_A$ and $P_A$. We choose to toss one of the coins with respect to a probability, then we toss it several times but we only inform the user when the outcome is heads. When the user sees one outcome, which is heads, he couldn't know how many times the coin has been flipped, since he didn't get notified of the number of tails outcome. So how can the user predict which coin has been tossed after knowing one heads and calculate its posterior probability?

Comment: He cannot. If $P_a$ and $P_b$ are non-zero, then surely any of the two will show heads sooner or later.

Comment: Unless exactly one of $P_A$ and $P_B$ is $0$ (and the user knows this), or some other information is given regarding the number of flips, there is no way for the user to determine this.

Comment: @BrianTung I also guess that the user can't predict the coin, but has the user gained any information about coins? 
When I try to write down probabilities I can't reach to a conclusion that the evidence doesn't leak information to the user, but intuitively it seems that the user doesn't gain any information.

Comment: @Tavish Can you provide a reasoning that the evidence has no information for the user?

Comment: @mahdi I already did. Both the coins are bound to show heads, without knowing the number of tails before, there’s no way to predict anything.